# ag-grid server-side search (getRows() needs an extra param)

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I am using virtual paging and I have a dataSource which does the work nicely. My function getRows (compulsory to be implemented in the dataSource) does an http request.

I would like to have an input in which the user can type and run a search (http) against my data with his input. Virtual paging means the search happens in the server.

The problem is that any dataSource that I provide should implement getRows(params). I would need to have getRows(params, searchInput). Ag-grid won't provide me with the input with the actual mechanism, but I need the mechanism to keep the virtual paging.

A solution would be to have a "global" variable outside the function that would be updated by the user and then inside getRows use it for the request. I find this rather sneaky and not "good programming".

Find the "getRows" related documentation: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid-datasource/index.php

Any idea would be welcomed.
Thank you very much.